# Iterating through a Linked List in another class (Java Applet)

Tags: java, oop, applet

I have this code for when an applet button is pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    oval p;
    int x, y, height, width, fill;
    x = Integer.parseInt(xfield.getText());
    y = Integer.parseInt(yfield.getText());
    height = Integer.parseInt(heightf.getText());
    width = Integer.parseInt(widthf.getText());
    list.add(new oval(x,y,height,width));
    repaint();
}
```

I need to iterate through the list of ovals and draw them in this class:

```
public void draw(Graphics g)
 {
   ListIterator li;
   li = list.listIterator();
   while(li.hasNext())
   {
   g.drawOval(x, y, height, width);
   } 
}
```

How do I get my list into this class? Is there a way I can pass it to the class as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `private List<oval> ovals;` list to the class that contains the `actionPerformed` method, and add the ovals to that list (as it could like you're doing already).

Then you create a `public List<oval> getOvals()` method, and use that to access the list from your `draw` method in the other class.